# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied (even with administrator rights)

Tags: python, enthought, canopy, ioerror, intel-mkl

I am trying to run the following script using administrator rights (after creating a .bat file and run it as administrator): 
http://enthought-dev.117412.n3.nabble.com/attachment/2871546/0/rename_mkl.py

After I run the script I get the following error:

`C:\Windows\system32>python C:\Users\Adnane\Desktop\rename_mkl.py`     `C:\Users\Adnane\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages`

```
  `Traceback (most recent call last):`
     File "C:\Users\Adnane\Desktop\rename_mkl.py", line 124, in <module>
       main()
     File "C:\Users\Adnane\Desktop\rename_mkl.py", line 117, in main
       if not is_DLL(path):
     File "C:\Users\Adnane\Desktop\rename_mkl.py", line 49, in is_DLL
       fi = open(path, 'rb')
```

`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:` `'C:\\Users\\Adnane\\AppData\\Local\\Enthought\\Canopy\\User\\Lib\\site-packages'`

The error occured after I've installed the `MKL numpy` instead of the original numpy contained in the enthought canopy package (The MKL numpy is necessary in order to use the `cvxopt package`). The system complained with:

`OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found mk2iomp5md.dll already in
itialized.
OMP: Hint: This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have been linke
d into the program. That is dangerous, since it can degrade performance or cause
 incorrect results. The best thing to do is to ensure that only a single OpenMP
runtime is linked into the process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenM
P runtime in any library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you
 can set the environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program
 to continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrec
t results. For more information, please see http://www.intel.com/software/produc
ts/support/.`

I've read on the enthought dev website that runing this `rename_mkl.py` script should solve the problem, but when I run it I get the error mentionned above.

Please, is there any solution?

Comment: At present, all versions of Canopy are built with MKL numpy, so this might be a false trail. What happened when you tried to use cvxopt with the original Canopy install?

Comment: I got a `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found` when i try to import cvxopt. When I installed the MKL numpy from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy the `import cvxopt` worked fine but I got the `OMP: Error #15` mentionned above.